# Why does save function in express not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, routes

This is my first day in express. I was trying to create a simple route but my save function doesn't seem to work. I tried looking at similar questions posted on stackoverflow but couldn't make it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require("../models/Post");

//ROUTES

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    })

    post.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.json(err);
    }); 


});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my model.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts',PostSchema);
```

app.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require("dotenv/config");


//IMPORT ROUTES
const postsRoute = require("./routes/posts");

//MIDDLEWARE - Function that always execute when routes are being hit.
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/posts', postsRoute)
//app.use('/users', usersRoute)

//ROUTES
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("We are on home");
});

//CONNECT TO DB
mongoose.connect(
process.env.DB_CONNECTION, 
{ useNewUrlParser: true },
() => {
    console.log("DB Connected!!")
})

//How do we start listening to the server
app.listen(3000);
```

My postman query - 
[image: My Postman query screenshot]

Postman Response - 
[image]

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Which route not working? if its the post then you should create post request to test it, if you got error on console, add it to your question.

Comment: Kindly mention which error you are getting when you try to save :)

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Also, do you have proper Express middleware installed so that `req.body` will be populated on your POST request handler?  You do not show it in the code you posted.  Without it, `req.body` will be empty.

Comment: @mamounothman - The post one. I removed the other one from my question for less confusion. I was testing this from postman. There is no error on console. No errors anywhere.

Comment: @MianMuhammad - No errors on console to understand where am I going wrong. Just the data won't get saved to Mongo.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I'll append my post with the rest of my code.

Comment: @InquisitiveP kindly post a screen shot of poostman.

Comment: How is the POST data encoded?  Is it from an HTML form?  Or is it JSON from an Ajax call?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I just updated my post with the postman screenshot. Data is from an AJAX call.

Comment: @InquisitiveP you might not be requiring the dotenv correctly, you are requiring it like this `require("dotenv/config")`, while documentation says `require('dotenv').config()` [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Does it correctly getting you connected to database?

Comment: @MianMuhammad - I tried by changing it to that. Still no luck. My .env file looks like - DB_CONNECTION = mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds211099.mlab.com:11099/rest

Comment: @MianMuhammad - I have added a console statement after connecting to the database. My program prints the statement, "DB Connected!!". I am assuming connection is happening alright.

Comment: @InquisitiveP wait a minute, let me run your example on my machine.

Comment: @MianMuhammad - Thanks. It's not a github repo as of now. Else would give you the link.

Comment: whats the response to the POST request?

Comment: @Lux - Updated my post with the response screenshot. It says, "Could not receive response".

Comment: @MianMuhammad - I think I am doing something very silly. Just can't figure out what.

Comment: When it is showing `Could not receive response` in postman, what is the output in the console?

Comment: @MianMuhammad - I got the issue. I wasn't escaping a '@' in my Mongo password in the DB_CONNECTION string. I changed the password to something less complicated, it worked! Thank you so much for your time. :)

Comment: Apparently, you are missing some error handling and did not log such a straightforward error.  Log every error on your server.  Don't take shortcuts or get lazy with that.

Comment: @InquisitiveP great, keep digging, I just ran what you have provided above and it was working fine. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/eQBNQvH), though I used my local mongodb setup

Answer (score -1):

your `app.js` should be :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require("dotenv/config");


//MIDDLEWARE - Function that always execute when routes are being hit.
app.use(bodyParser.json())


   mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, {  useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('System could not connect to mongo server')
        console.log(err)
        process.exit()
    } else {
        console.log('System connected to mongo server')
    }
});


//ROUTES
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("We are on home");
});

//IMPORT ROUTES
const postsRoute = require("./routes/posts");

app.use('/posts', postsRoute)


app.listen(3000);
```

also add console log in router to check req.body :

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.body===',req.body);
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. These log messages helped me understand the issue. I wasn't escaping a '@' in my password in the DB_CONNECTION string. Thank you so much for your help.